# How can I get connected values of two times the same foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a situation that could easily be solved with 3 SQL queries, but I wonder if it can be done in one query.

I have the following tables:

```
  symbol                     similarity
  -------                    ------------

  id | name | latex          id | base_symbol_id | similar_symbol_id
```

I want to SELECT so that my result looks like this:

```
  query_result
  ------------

  similarity_id | base_formula_id | base_formula_name | base_formula_latex | similar_formula_id | similar_formula_name | similar_formula_latex
```

### Failed tries

I usual solve similar tasks with JOIN. But this time, the SELECT depends on another attribute I select ... I don't know how to do this. Here is my try (which of course failed):

```
SELECT `base_symbol_id`, `similar_symbol_id`, `latex`
FROM `similarity` 
JOIN `symbol` ON ((`symbol`.`id` = `base_symbol_id`) OR (`symbol`.`id` = `similar_symbol_id`))
```

gives

```
base_symbol_id | simlar_symbol_id | latex
10             | 11               | \alpha
10             | 11               | a
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your desired output and the table inputs to help us work with you on solving this issue.

Comment: @rekaszeru I'm sorry, I don't know what I should provide more that what I've already did.

Comment: You gave us a result, that you don't want. But we need an example with the some rows in your tables and the result of the query with an explanation, why this is the result.

Comment: @VMai I also gave a table that looks like I want it. However, I've already got an answer that does what I want.

Comment: Why does `similarity` have an `id`?

Comment: @Rudie: Because it's simpler for me this way. I know, I don't need it as `base_symbol_id` and `similar_symbol_id` together are a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select sim.id
,base.id
,base.name
,base.latex
,similar.id
,similar.name
,similar.latex
from similarity as sim
join symbol as base on base.id=sim.base_symbol_id 
join symbol as similar on similar.id=sim.similar_symbol_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the given table structure, and making up some random sample inputs in an **[SQL Fiddle session](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72e8d/1)**, the following query would work as you desired:

```
SELECT T.id as similarity_id, 
      S1.id as base_formula_id, S1.name as base_formula_name, S1.latex as base_formula_latex,
      S2.id as similar_formula_id, S2.name as similar_formula_name, S2.latex as similar_formula_latex
  FROM similarity T
  LEFT OUTER JOIN symbol S1 ON (T.base_symbol_id = S1.id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN symbol S2 ON (T.similar_symbol_id = S2.id)
```